# Generating values based on mean and std listed in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame of this format:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    1: {'mean': 1.0, 'std': 0.8},
    2: {'mean': 0.5, 'std': 0.2},
    3: {'mean': 0.2, 'std': 0.1},
    4: {'mean': 0.1, 'std': 0.1},
    5: {'mean': 0.6, 'std': 0.2}
})

df
        1    2    3    4    5
mean  1.0  0.5  0.2  0.1  0.6
std   0.8  0.2  0.1  0.1  0.2
```

Based on these values of `mean` and `std`, I am trying to generate a big data frame of randomly generated numbers normally distributed, which has the same number of columns but more rows:

```py
full_noise = []

for mean, std in enumerate(df):
    noise = np.random.normal(mean, std, [5, 1000]) 
    full_noise.append(noise)
```

So, each column of this new data frame will have values generated on `mean` and `std` listed in the data frame above. I am definitely doing something wrong, though.

Sorry, I am quite new to Python! I hope you can help :(

Comment: Are you sure you want this `mean, std in enumerate(df):`? It will set `mean` with numbers in `range(len(df))`.

Comment: No, I am not sure at all about enumerate here.. Just don't have a clue how to loop through these columns for both mean and std to then plug the values into np.random.normal function..

Answer (score 2):

To create what you want I would suggest iterating over the dataframe `df` one column at a time (to do so first transpose the dataframe and then use `iterrows`).

For each column you can generate a numpy array of the lenght you desire from a normal distribution using the mean and std from the column.

At the end you can concatenate the numpy arrays as columns of a dataframe (so along `axis=1`).

```py
full_noise = []
for _, col in df.T.iterrows():
    noise = np.random.normal(loc=col["mean"], scale=col["std"], size=(1000,))
    full_noise.append(pd.Series(noise))

noise_df = pd.concat(full_noise, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.apply` to make `full_noise`.

```py
full_noise = df.apply(
    lambda col: np.random.normal(loc=col["mean"], scale=col["std"], size=(1_000,)),
)

print(full_noise)
```

```
            1         2         3         4         5
0    0.900445  0.555275  0.206491  0.161578  0.491196
1    1.555625  0.261742  0.196981 -0.068225  0.770397
2    0.308983  0.256334  0.119617  0.157978  0.453351
3    0.799080  0.255109  0.164719 -0.088953  0.462583
4    1.263621  0.650327  0.217544  0.046004  0.893409
..        ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
995  1.345332  0.827836  0.320708  0.113350  0.789898
996  1.235461  0.464576  0.270596  0.049924  0.708799
997  1.211508  0.751700  0.230916  0.176736  0.661312
998  1.753942  0.941567  0.097372  0.177429  0.810710
999  1.847943  0.240993 -0.006139  0.200517  0.523238

[1000 rows x 5 columns]
```